# Why result of the function call is undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, call, console.log

Why array can't be displayed immediately after swap function call in JS? Why result of the function call is undefined?

```js
    const swap = (arr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            var tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = tmp;
        }

    }

    r = [...Array(10)].map( (_, i) => (i + 1) * 3);
    console.log(r);         // --> Array [ 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30 ]
    //swap(r);

    // why array can't be displayed immediately after swap  function call?
    console.log( swap(r) ); // --> displays undefined but the swap function worked out
    console.log(r);         // --> Array [ 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 3 ]
```

I think it's because the swap function returns nothing but I'm not sure. But

```js
swap(r);
console.log(r);
```

works fine.

Comment: That's exactly why. The array is modified in place, but the function does not return anything. Add `return arr;` at the end of the function and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, it's because you are trying to output the result of the `swap` function call but you are not returning anything specific. So the default result is undefined.

If you want to output the array after the swap, then return that in your function like so:

```js
const swap = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    var tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = tmp;
  }
  return arr;
}

r = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => (i + 1) * 3);
console.log(swap(r));
```

Ultimately it is up to you to decide how you want the function to work. As you have identified there is no need to return anything at all as long as you don't try and use the result of the function call.

With regards to why it doesn't automatically return the array, well you have to remember that a function can do lots of different things to many objects. There would be no way to know which object or value should automatically be returned, so it doesn't make sense for it to try and do anything magic like that. If you want something returned, then make sure you return it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return anything and leave your function `swap` as it.  The passed array is a reference of `r = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => (i + 1) * 3)` so, every modification will modify that array after the function `swap` ends.

Just print the array `console.log(r);`.

```js
const swap = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    var tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    arr[i + 1] = tmp;
  }
}

r = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => (i + 1) * 3);
console.log(r); // --> Array [ 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30 ]
swap(r);

// why array can't be displayed immediately after swap  function call?
//    console.log(swap(r)); // --> displays undefined but the swap function worked out
console.log(r); // --> Array [ 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 3 ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right; you should use `return arr;` but I think what you want is rotating the array.

```js
arr = new Array(10).fill().map( (_, i) => (i + 1) * 3);
console.log(arr);
res = [...arr.slice(1),arr[0]]; // prettier but can be dramatically slow on large arrays
// or for even faster one :
rotate = (arr) => !(arr.push(arr.shift())) || arr;
// or
/*const rotate = (arr) => {
  var first = arr[0];
  for(var c = 0, l = arr.length - 1; c < l;)
    arr[c] = arr[++c];
  arr[arr.length-1] = first;
  return arr;
}*/
console.log(res);
console.log(rotate(arr));
```

Comment: The question is not about the logic of the function. You should not make assumptions about this if the OP has not mentioned it

Comment: @musefan Is it better now ?

Comment: Thank you @nullqube!  Why it's not good practice to change the array inside a function?

Comment: your welcome. you can search for "loose coupling" and "side effect", it's when a function change something outside of it's scope; you can read more here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15269/why-are-side-effects-considered-evil-in-functional-programming . and by the way if you want to change the array itself it's better to extend Array.prototype so it become more obvious like arr.rotate().

Comment: Thank @nullqube for article! When I write something I try to create as little garbage as possible. If I can modify target object I will do it without creating garbage. Here nice article about optimization https://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/writing-efficient-javascript-a-few-tips/  Which is the worst evil, side effects or garbage collector?